# Iframe not going full screen

Tags: html, iframe, fullscreen

as the title says, i can't manage to have a full scren iframe.

Here is the code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="p'+item.id+'"><div data-role="header" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border:none;" data-position="fixed"><a href="#" onClick="location.href=\'documenti.html\'" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left">Home</a><img src="images/app/logo.png" id="navImg"/></div><iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://' + item.path + '" width="100%" height="100%" align="center" ></iframe></div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/579sxg8s/

Comment: @Abhishek i need a responsive iframe that takes full screen, that's why i can't set a fixed height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this to your first div element:

```
style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"
```

set the height and width of the div to 100% of the *viewportheight* / *viewportwidth*

Since you already have the iframe set to be 100% for both height and width, it will inherit the size of its containing element, so setting the height and width of that div to the viewport height and viewport width, the iframe will fill 100% of that space both in width and height.

updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/john_h/579sxg8s/2/

Comment: This is correct. Unfortunately it didn't work in my full code, it's very strange since "width" works but "height" still remains the same. Do you know a possible reason?

Comment: Can you show the full code?  If there are other divs that have set widths/heights they may be overriding what you want to display.

Comment: nevermind, i solved using inAppBrowser (it was a jquery mobile code). I marked you answer as correct anyway, since it solved what i asked in this thread. :) Thank you